# Does target blank on internal links affect Google Analytics and search engines in any way?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, html, links

We have a news site where many articles have "Read more" links. These internal links are often set with the attribute `target="_blank"`, links opens in a new tab.

Does it have any affect on Google Analytics and SEO?

Comment: No. Why would it? It is not a good thing to do from a user experience (UX) point of view except in some small cases where it makes sense. You may see a significant drop-off in user engagement in your reports if you over-do it. That is is.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! But it's not the best practice to have a link open in a new window/tab if you remain on the same site (unless it's opening up a PDF or other document). Using `target="_blank"` is usually reserved for external links.

Comment: "it's not the best practice" can you cite a reputable source for that to improve your answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. SEO have nothing to do about `target="_blank"` information, They crawl pages individual.
2. Analytics report show you two things, first from where you're getting traffics and how user interact with your site, like bounce rate, clicks, time spent, goals etc. The other last things is not going to affect at all, because it get information from page it self. But the first thing like from where you're getting traffic is purely depend on [browser HTTP header information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), like HOST, Referer, User Agent, Origin, Accept-Language etc Fields. **And those information will still pass when user open link in new tab.** Google analytics may gives you wrong information when someone use serices like `nullrefer.com` because it hide original HTTP referrer information, but as I said target="_blank" does not affect anything in HTTP headers fields, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

It does not impact your Google Analytics data per se.

However, I do not know whether it impacts SEO or not (since the ranking factors themselves are not disclosed).

Google has a tool called as [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) which is supposed to help developers in improving the quality of the web pages. This documentation catches _blank links and frowns upon the usage as there is some [security vulnerability there](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener).

TL;DR - rethink the _blank because of the security issues it represents

Comment: Looks to me that it should just be a matter of adding rel="noopener", so:
   target="_blank" rel="noopener"